# kotlin dagger "'<any>' could not be resolved"

Tags: kotlin, dagger

I have working java code

```
public class ItemCallback<T extends Identifiable<?>> extends DiffUtil.ItemCallback<T> {

    @Inject
    public ItemCallback() {}

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull T oldItem, @NonNull T newItem) {
        return oldItem.getId().equals(newItem.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull T oldItem, @NonNull T newItem) {
        return oldItem.compareContent(newItem);
    }
}
```

and i wrote correspond kotlin code

```
class ItemCallback<T : ListElementModel<*>> @Inject constructor() : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<T>() {

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: T, newItem: T): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: T, newItem: T): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

and caught error
"error: InjectProcessingStep was unable to process 'ItemCallback()' because 'any' could not be resolved."

I understand that the error in star-projections. But I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Has `Identifiable` been renamed to `ListElementModel`, or are those two different types?

Comment: @Egor is renamed